# Functions having closure on different versions of the same function scope

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

Consider this piece of code:

```
function foo(a){
        setTimeout(function(){
            debugger;
            a;
        }, 1000);
    }

    foo(1);
    foo(2);
    foo(3);
```

What happens is that each function call gets the right value of a when its relative setTimeout function was called, so that somehow implies that each of the passed callback functions has a closure on the foo function's scope but each has a snapshot of that scope at a certain point in time, but I can't get my head around this explanation or I'm missing what a scope means in the first place, can any one elaborate ? thanks.

Comment: Hard to wrap head around what you are asking or what the confusion is

Comment: I'm confused that the callback functions have closures on the foo function's scope but with different state(each has a different value of a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure is basically just a function reference tied together with a reference to the *enclosing scope record*. So in your case:

```
  setTimeout(function(){
```

Thats the function that gets closured, and the scope it is executed in is the intermediate scope record of the current execution of foo. When you call:

```
  foo(1)
```

a new scope record gets created with `a` being `1`, usually this record would be discarded when foo finishes its execution, but as the closure keeps a reference to it, this does not happen. Now when the timeout finishes, the closure gets executed and the reference to the closure gets lost, therefore the reference to the enclosing scope record gets lost too and `a` is finally garbage collected. When you call `foo` multiple times, multiple records and closures get created, therefore `a` can evaluate to different values in the callbacks as they are resolved to different records.

Comment: So it's actually different scopes being created for every call of foo ?

Comment: @mohamed i prefer to call them *scope records* but yes, thats what happens